# How do I keep event_id in sync with client and server for facebook Conversion API?

Tags: facebook, uniqueidentifier, ids

For facebook Conversion API to work I need to generate a unique event_id that is the same on browser and server, so that facebook can deduplicate it.

More on this here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events

Now my problem is, that sometimes the server fires an event first, sometimes the client.
So generating IDs on client first or on server first is tricky to do (at least, I would have to refactor quite a lot).

Is there any other way to reliably build unique IDs on browser and server without them communicating to each other?

Comment: Take some information that is available on both the client and the server side, and hash it?

Comment: Thank you :) Yes - the thing is just -> it needs to be always unique. So let's take userId for example: If a user makes 2 times the PageView, the eventId is not unique anymore. Which is a problem according to facebook.